# Include arbitrary field in Rails model JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails as a REST server, and one of my models has a description field. In that model's JSON representation, I need to output both the regular description field AND an arbitrary non-DB attribute called description_markdown that is just the description run through a markdown filter. I already know how to run text through markdown using redcarpet, like:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true, :fenced_code_blocks => true, :lax_html_blocks => true)
description_markdown = markdown.render(@post.description).html_safe
```

But what I really need is to make `description_markdown` an attribute on @post (like @post.description_markdown), and have it output in @post's JSON representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally use RABL gem to build JSON views for my APIs -- it gives you a lot of flexibility on building JSON responses, such as creating custom child nodes, adding arbitrary code. Check it out.
But, to answer your question, you can probably overwrite `as_json` method of `Post` to include the return of `description_markdown`. Something like (not tested):

```
#post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def description_markdown
    ...
  end
  ...
  def as_json(options)
    super(:only => [:attributes_you_want], :methods => [:description_markdown])
  end
  ...
end
```

Then, in controller:

```
render :json => @post
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `description_markdown` to your model:

```
def description_markdown
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true, :fenced_code_blocks => true, :lax_html_blocks => true)
    markdown.render(description).html_safe
end
```

Then add that to your model's [`as_json` using `:methods`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json):

```
def as_json(options = { })
    super((options || { }).merge({
        :methods => [:description_markdown]
    }))
end
```

That would add your `description_markdown` output to your model's standard JSON representation. The `options || { }` is there in case someone hands you a `nil` for `options`, then we merge our `:methods` into the options, and hand it off to ActiveRecord::Base for the heavy lifting. You'll need more complicated merging for `options` if you want outsiders to be able to send in their own `:methods` values.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an alternative in case you're defining what fields/data you need in the controller (like you might in a Rails 4 app), like so:

```
Post.to_json(only: [], methods: [:generate_markdown])
```

in your Post code, add:

```
def generate_markdown
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true, :fenced_code_blocks => true, :lax_html_blocks => true)
    return markdown.render(@post.description).html_safe
```